# Priority element in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two element in the same page:

one is into a div and another one is into an overlay.

I want to display only the element inside the overlay and not element in the page (it is also hide by overlay).

I don't know how can I prevent this... I bind the directive by attributes, maybe should I pass some other params to element?

This is plunker example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aAtMoviVkqEjUxej893L?p=preview)

As you can see, I want to hide text in page when modal (simple example, but I use another plugin) is open and show it in modal and viceversa... I preferer to use only directive and/or some more attributes in the element...

I test a lot but I don't find solution...

Code:

```
angular...[]....directive('example', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.display = "IT's WORK TEXT BY DIRECTIVE";
        }
    };
});


<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <!--Modal-->
    <div class="modal-body">
        <span example="" class="text-danger"><br><br>{{display}}<br><br></span>
    </div>
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
<span example="" class="text-danger"><br><br>{{display}}<br><br></span>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you only looking to hide the 'display' text when the modal is open or are you also looking to display this 'display' text within the modal once it has been opened?

Comment: I want: when modal open->display text only in modal; when close display only in div;

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of ng-show and a js closure passed to the modal for toggling the visibility of your text. So... the display visibility will be controlled by the ng-show

```
<span example="" ng-show="elemVisibility" class="text-danger"><br><br>{{display}}<br><br></span>
```

You can toggle the visibility with a js helper function

```
function _setElemVisiblity (isModalOpen) {
   $scope.elemVisibility = !isModalOpen;
}
```

You can pass this as a callback to your modal and trigger it whenever you open/close the modal.

[Updated plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oAxA9qn86lerxdm65LeO)

Comment: No you dont mention explicitly that you dont want to add code to the controller. Also the modal has to somehow communicate to the view and/or directive whenever it has been opened/closed. This can either be done in the modal controller or your view controller.